# How to open An Activity by Clicking On FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

In fact i know how to open an activity by clicking on a button

But i can't do it in frame layout

i try this code but it didn't help me.

```
 FrameLayout ff=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    ff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(listActivity.this,bookActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

that's all

EDITES:

this my activity_main :

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linbook"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linjozve"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <FrameLayout

                    android:id="@+id/ketabbtn"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="130dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:id="@+id/btntopright"
                        android:layout_width="130dp"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rgreen"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:background="@drawable/book"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp" />

                </FrameLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="book"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: had you run your code in debug mode and checked what's going on ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it is quite hard to click on a `FrameLayout` if it is covered by other views. In your case, the `framelayout` and the `imagebutton` have the same size `130x130`. This explains why the touch cannot reach the layout.

To make sure you can click it, add some padding between the layout and its childs. (I reduced the size of its child)

```
<FrameLayout
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/ketabbtn"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="130dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/btntopright"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rgreen"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:background="@drawable/book"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Also, you used **wrong ID**. So change this:

```
FrameLayout ff=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

To this:

```
FrameLayout ff=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.ketabbtn);
```

So you can click the padding space to trigger the `onClick` event.

Comment: You used a wrong ID `R.id.ketabbtn`. See the updated answer

Comment: @tung-d-nguyen i think i should use framelayout id . no ?

Comment: You definitely should use the `framelayout` id (`@+id/ketabbtn`). But you used  `findViewById(R.id.btn);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set android:clickable in the xml. 
If that doesn't work try to create a custom layout:
 By default, onInterceptTouchEvent returns false.  So include following code and use this CustomClickableFrameLayout instead of framelayout

```
public class CustomClickableFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private OnClickListener mOnClickListener;

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        super.setOnClickListener(l);
        mOnClickListener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return mOnClickListener != null;
    }


    // Standard constructors — just pass everything
    public CustomClickableFrameLayout (final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomClickableFrameLayout (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomClickableFrameLayout (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomClickableFrameLayout (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr, final int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry dear @D Agrawal where should i write this code?

Comment: Add this as a separate class. And then in your xml instead of <FrameLayout></FrameLayout> use <CustomClickableFrameLayout ></CustomClickableFrameLayout > .Also while declaring in your activity , declare it as CustomClickableFrameLayout ff=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.btn);    . I also notice that your framelayout id in activity and xml differ. click if u properly assigned.

Comment: framelayout won't TypeCast this class @D Agrawal